# Windows mp3/mp4 streaming

Tags: iphone, windows

I need stream audio/video data from Windows server to iPhone application. Do somebody know any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but if someone else comes across it like I did I want to point them in the right direction.
Microsoft offers this ability now with IIS 7 and IIS Media Services 4.0.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/854/apple-http-live-streaming-with-iis-media-services/

Answer (score 0):

Stream in shoutcast format from the PC (http header + raw mpeg packets) and play it back on the iPhone using an `AVPlayer` or even an invisible `WebView` if you want a quick fix.